# Save information except last digit in line - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to save to an `ArrayList` every number but the last digit of each line of the file.

The file looks like this:

```
8.1,6.5,4.4,3.2,1

8.9,5,1.4,0.1,1

8.7,6.2,4.3,3.2,3
```

I have this code but that just saves everything in the `ArrayList`:

```java
try (Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter(",")) {
    while (file.hasNextLine()) {
        arr.add(file.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: So...what's wrong with your code?

Comment: I want the code to ignore the last digit of each line.

Comment: There is one problem and it's very clearly expressed by the poster. I'm not sure how they could get it across any more easily.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you would need to get the individual numbers and exclude the last one yourself. I would do it like this:

```java
try (Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter(",")) {
    while (file.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = file.nextLine();
        
        // Split the numbers
        String[] numbers = line.split(",");
        
        // Store the length of the last number
        int lastNumberLength = numbers[numbers.length - 1].length();

        // Make a substring that doesn't include the last number.
        // The minus one is because there's a comma there too.
        line = line.substring(0, line.length() - lastNumberLength - 1);
        
        // Add the now-edited line to the list
        arr.add(line);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: My answer is wrong. This will save the entire line as a string in the ArrayList without the last number. Please refer to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the stream API that was added in Java 8.
(Note that below code also uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).)

```java
/*
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
 */
try (Stream<String> strm = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
    List<Double> list = strm.flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(line.split(","), 0, 4)))
                            .map(Double::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}
```

- Method [lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), in class `java.nio.file.Files`, returns a stream where every element in the stream is a line from the file *files.txt*.
- Method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), in class `java.lang.String`, splits each line on the commas and creates an array of `String`. Since each line in the file contains four commas, a five element array will be created from each line of the file.
- Method [copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-), in class `java.util.Arrays`, will return another array containing only the first four elements of the array returned by method `split`.
- Method `stream`, also in class `java.util.Arrays`, will create a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from the array returned by method `copyOfRange`.
- Method `flatMap`, in interface `Stream`, will combine all the streams into a single stream (of `String`s).
- Method `map`, in interface `Stream`, will convert the `String`s to `Double`s by calling [static] method [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) in class `java.lang.Double`.
- Finally the stream elements are collected into a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (of `Double`s).

Running the above code, with the sample data in your question, prints the following list:

```
[8.1, 6.5, 4.4, 3.2, 8.9, 5.0, 1.4, 0.1, 8.7, 6.2, 4.3, 3.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Read each line as String, split the string and cast it into an ArrayList

```
        ArrayList<Double> arrList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File("Filename_and_Filepath"))){
            
            //put each line in a String
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String a = scanner.nextLine();
                
                //split string by ,
                String[] array = a.split(",");
                
                //add into ArrayList after type casting
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
                    arrList.add(Double.parseDouble(array[i]));
                } 
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take with a bit of a hybrid method which conveys the intent without getting too procedural and avoiding extra cloning of things. It will work with lines with an arbitrary number of numbers, it will just skip the last one:

```
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
            lines.forEachOrdered(line -> {
                String[] items = line.split(",");
                Arrays.stream(items)
                        .limit(items.length - 1)
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .forEachOrdered(arr::add);
            });
        }
```

Note:

- the `.map(String::trim)` will trim extra whitespace characters surrounding the numbers. If you know you'll never have extra spaces in your input you can remove this line.
- the OQ made no mention of wanting to convert the numbers to `Double`. If you do want the conversion, add in a `.map(Double::valueOf)` to convert your numbers to `Double`, right after the trimming.